# Error: Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM in React.js and Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, next.js

I am Currently using React Router, when I execute code and enter in my interface localhost:3000 the code is Break and shown this error msg: "Error: Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM", can anyone have solution for this type of Error?

Comment: Please check here : https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Next.js provides its own [built-in router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) - you should use that instead. See also [Migrating from React Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router)